# ReactJs problem with route only in production server

Tags: reactjs

So I have a menu and each tab on the menu display a different page.
my menu looks like this

```
export default function() {
  return [
    {
      title: "Account",
      to: "/account-information",
    },
    {
      title: "Orders",
      to: "/orders",
    },

  ];
}
```

then I also have a route that looks like this

```
export default [
  {
    path: "/account",
    exact: true,
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/account-information" />
  },
  {
    path: "/account-information",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: AccountOverview
  },
  {
    path: "/orders",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Orders
  },

];
```

the my index.js display the pages depending on which tab you click on. the code looks like this

```
  <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
    <div>
      {routes.map((route, index) => {
        return (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={withTracker(props => {
              return (
                <route.layout {...props}>
                  <route.component {...props} />
                </route.layout>
              );
            })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </Router>
```

My problem is that everything works great when testing locally on my machine, however once I deploy it and I lick on a tab on the menu I see the URL changing but the page stay blank and does not display the right page
any idea?

Comment: Where are you hosting the react app?

Comment: have you set the REACT_APP_BASENAME env var in the production environment?